# Android App dev Loading flash with webview tablet

Tags: java, javascript, android

I am new to android, I have created a simple app to load a flash player into
a webview. My flash player contains a presentation which is saved in 2 folders in the 
assets
folder 1 is Data
folder 2 is Player
and my player.html

The app get installed into the tablet and starts running but once the loading bar get
half way trough it, it stay like that without completing.

This is my Activity Java file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
 final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/player.html");
}

}
```

And Here is my XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="HTML in WEB View"
    tools:context="MainActivity" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I have the hardware accelerated as true on the manifest

Can someone please let me know where the problem could be.

My assumptions will be
Need to grant file access to the asset folder?
Do I need to put all my files in the assets folder with no subfolder?
Is Webview waiting for me to click on an invisible pop-up window allowing flash to 
access the files?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application that generated the flash files came back with an answer stating that it is not compatible with android development.